# Set the text opacity with fogleman/gg

Tags: image, go

My use-case is adding a watermark to an image. However the text is solid and makes it difficult to see the contents underneath. I have tried linear gradients and fill patterns, but they still result in the same opacity.

Maybe fogleman/gg isn't the appropriate library for this, but it is pretty embedded in my app so I would like to us it.

```
import (]
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "strings"

    "github.com/fogleman/gg"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)


func setImgWatermark(img image.Image, text string) (image.Image, error) {
    dc := gg.NewContextForImage(img)
    if err := dc.LoadFontFace(fontPath, 100.0); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "dc.LoadFontFace")
    }

    dc.SetColor(color.RGBA{158, 158, 158, 255})

    x, y := float64(dc.Width()/2), 0.0
    dc.Translate(x, y)
    dc.Rotate(gg.Radians(-45))
    dc.DrawStringAnchored(strings.Repeat(text, 5), x, y, 0.5, 0.5)

    return dc.Image(), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok. Learning a lot about colors today. You can set the rgba on the context. The "a" stands for alpha!

this did the trick for me:

```
dc.SetRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
```

I didn't read far enough down on this issue when researching.

https://github.com/fogleman/gg/issues/183